# Missing rtl150.bpl when adding a package

Tags: delphi, bpl

I am trying to recompile old Delphi program from 2011 which uses external bpl packages. They are named as SentrolBase150.bpl and so on but when I am trying to import those packages I am getting an error message saying rtl150.bpl not found.

I looked to Delphi install folder and found rtl240.bpl there (I have installed RAD Studio 10.1 version).

Is there way to use those old existing bpl packages or do I have to rebuild package from scratch? I have full source code but I don't know (yet) how to build it.

Or have I misunderstood something. I haven't done Delphi programming since 90s.

Comment: .Dcu files are not generally compatible across and neither afaik are BPLs, so you will need to rebuild the package for your current Delphi version or obtain one from Sentrol's suppliers (https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-sdk-sentrol/ ?)  It looks like they have a trial version available.

Comment: Sentrol does not distribute source code except in the Professional SKU, and even then they only give you the `.pas` files, and not all of them (`SentrolVersion.pas` is missing, for example) - there is no project file that defines the individual packages so a rebuild may not be an option.  This is presumably to discourage user recompiles vs upgrading. Upgrades to new compiler versions can be expensive. Your Berlin licence should allow you to install an older version of Delphi - the xx150.bpl files associate with Delphi XE so a simple option would be to install Delphi XE and compile with that.